# Restrict User Interface in Excel while macro is running

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4-5 workbooks open and one workbook has macro written for copying of data from other workbooks.
But if a user is working on some other workbook while the macro is running, excel freezes and goes into not responding mode.

How do I disable user interface in this case for all workbooks till macro completes it's coding?

Answer (score 1):

Display a "modal" userform while the macro runs. Users are unable to interact with Excel while the form is displayed.

It could be as simple as having just a label on the form saying "Please wait while macro runs".  If the macro takes more than a few seconds to run, you could display a progress bar.

You will probably need to use the QueryClose event to stop the user clicking the close button in the top right corner of the form.